# How to pull data from access to excel using vba by by checking a column in excel

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vba, excel

I have tried the following to retrieve info. from an access database to an excel file:

```
Sub ddd()

Const dbloc As String = "C:\Users\mysystem1\Downloads\Database11.accdb"
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim xlbook As Workbook
Dim xlsheet As Worksheet
Dim a As Long
Dim SQL As String

Set xlbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set xlsheet = xlbook.Worksheets(1)
xlsheet.Range("A5:Z100000").ClearContents
Application.StatusBar = "Connecting to external database..."

Set db = OpenDatabase(dbloc)

SQL = "SELECT  Material_ID "
SQL = SQL & "FROM Sheet1"    
'Sheet1 is the the access tablename
'SQL = SQL & "WHERE Material IN (500017,500024,500029)"  
' i want to update the where condition above to a column in the excel wb itself



Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenSnapshot)

If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then

MsgBox "No data retrieved from database", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "No Data"
    GoTo SubExit

Else

    rs.MoveLast

    recCount = rs.RecordCount

    rs.MoveFirst

End If

xlsheet.Range("C5").CopyFromRecordset rs

End Sub
```

I want to update the where condition in my sql query to return results based on a column from the Excel wb. But I am not getting the correct syntax.

please help.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Michal, can you help me with the correct syntax regards the SQL where condition to check a column from Excel

Answer (score 1):

```
 SQL = SQL & "WHERE Material IN (" & range("a1") & "," & range("A2") & " ," & range("a3") & ")"
```

You literally replace the values with the cell references, but ensure that the references are outside your speech marks.

If you wanted to do more cells you could do

```
  SQL = SQL & "WHERE Material IN ("
  Dim r as range
  For each r in range("a1:A20")
       SQL = SQL & r.text & ","
  Next r
  SQL = left(SQL,LEN(SQL)-1)  'Drop last comma
  Sql = SQL &  & ")"
```

Comment: This is working fine for a range of about 5k rows. But is there a quicker method if i want to check from a list of 70-80k rows?

Comment: Do it in Access. Use External data in Access to link to the column in the Excel sheet as a table (it will need a row heading). Then join the excel table to sheet1.Material  in a query.

Comment: Your help has been incredibly helpful so far. can you please help with the syntax for the above. i am currently doing      Set col1 = Range(Range("A1:Z1").Find("Material").Offset(1, 0), Range("A1:Z1").Find("Material").End(xlDown)) to get the range of my table in  excel. How do i use this in my query. I am just starting out and having trouble with syntaxes here. Thanks a ton!!

Comment: If your excel sheet has column labels, then use the import wizard in Access to Link to the excel sheet. It will treat the label "Material" as a field name, and will automatically use all the rows with data. Then use the Query Wizard in Access to build your linked table query and check it's retrieving the right data. Then switch to SQL View and copy the sql text. You can then paste that into your vba . Just make sure that your excel sheet is not called Sheet1 when you link, because you've already used that name in Access.

Comment: I can work with the Table i mentioned, in my above comment. I am new to macros and access, can you please help with the syntax for the following?       Dim col1 as Range;   Set col1 = Range(Range("A1:Z1").Find("Material").Offset(1, 0), Range("A1:Z1").Find("Material").End(xlDown)) . How should i proceed further with this?